# React Redux - How to make a double dispatch

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm fetch some data from my API and it correctly works. But when a double dispatch on the same page the API doesn't work anymore. It's better code to explain it:

Server:

```
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  let sql = "SELECT * FROM design_categories";
  let query = connection.query(sql, (err, results) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.send(results);
  });
});
 
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  let sql = "SELECT * FROM food_categories";
  let query = connection.query(sql, (err, results) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.send(results);
  });
});
```

They work.

action.js

```
export const fetchDesignCat = () => {
  setLoading()
  return async dispatch => {
    const response = await axios
      .get("http://localhost:5000/api/designcategories")
      .then(results => results.data)

    try {
      await dispatch({ type: FETCH_DESIGN_CAT, payload: response })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("await error", error)
    }
  }
}
     
export const fetchFoodCat = () => {
  setLoading()
  return async dispatch => {
    const response = await axios
      .get("http://localhost:5000/api/foodcategories")
      .then(results => results.data)

    try {
      await dispatch({ type: FETCH_FOOD_CAT, payload: response })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("await error", error)
    }
  }
}
```

Both of them work perfectly.

reducer.js

```
const initalState = {
  db: [],
  loading: true,
  designcat: [],
  foodcat: [],
}
export default (state = initalState, action) => {
 switch (action.type) {
// different cases

  case FETCH_DESIGN_CAT:
      return {
        designcat: action.payload,
        loading: false,
      }
    case FETCH_FOOD_CAT:
      return {
        food: action.payload,
        loading: false,
      }

}
```

The reducer updates the states perfectly.

Page settings.js

```
const Settings = ({ designcat, foodcat, loading }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

// ... code 


useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchDesignCat()) // imported action
    dispatch(fetchFoodCat()) // imported action
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [])

// ... code that renders 

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  designcat: state.appDb.designcat,
  foodcat: state.appDb.foodcat,
  loading: state.appDb.loading,
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchDesignCat, fetchFoodCat })(
  Settings
)
```

Now there's the problem. If I use just one dispatch it's fine I get one or the other. **But if I use the both of them look like the if the second overrides the first**. This sounds strange to me.

From my ReduxDevTools

[image]

For sure I'm mistaking somewhere. Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Just so you know, [double dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) refers to a specific software engineering concept :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your reducer does not merge the existing state with the new state, which is why each of the actions just replace the previous state. You'll want to copy over the other properties of the state and only replace the ones your specific action should replace. Here I'm using [object spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals) to do a shallow copy of the previous state:

```
export default (state = initalState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_DESIGN_CAT:
      return {
        ...state, // <----
        designcat: action.payload,
        loading: false,
      }
    case FETCH_FOOD_CAT:
      return {
        ...state, // <----
        food: action.payload,
        loading: false,
      }
  }
}
```

Since the code is abbreviated, I'm assuming you're handling the `default` case correctly.

As an additional note, since you're using `connect` with the `Settings` component, you don't need to `useDispatch` and can just use the already connected action creators provided via props by `connect`:

```
const Settings = ({
  designcat,
  foodcat,
  loading,
  fetchDesignCat,
  fetchFoodCat,
}) => {
  // ... code
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchDesignCat();
    fetchFoodCat();
  }, [fetchDesignCat, fetchFoodCat]);

  // ... code that renders
};
```

There's also a race condition in the code which may or may not be a problem to you. Since you start both `FETCH_DESIGN_CAT` and `FETCH_FOOD_CAT` at the same time and both of them set `loading: false` after finishing, when the first of them finishes, `loading` will be false but the other action will still be loading its data. If this case is known and handled in code (i.e., you don't trust that both items will be present in the state if `loading` is `false`) that's fine as well.

The solution to that would be either to combine the fetching of both of these categories into one thunk, or create separate sub-reducers for them with their own `loading` state properties. Or of course, you could manually set and unset `loading`.